# Kalman Filter with acceleration

Tags: c++, opencv, kalman-filter

I am trying to implement a Kalman filter based mouse tracking (as a test first) using a velocity-acceleration model.

I want to try this out this simple model, my state transition equations are:

```
X(k) = [x(k), y(k)]'   (Position)
V(k) = [vx(k), vy(k)]' (Velocity)
X(k) = X(k-1) + dt*V(k-1) + 0.5*dt*dt*a(k-1)
V(k) = V(k-1) + t*a(k-1)
a(k) = a(k-1)
```

Using this I have basically wrote down the following piece of code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


struct mouse_info_struct { int x,y; };
struct mouse_info_struct mouse_info = {-1,-1}, last_mouse;

void on_mouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    //if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP)
    {
        last_mouse = mouse_info;
        mouse_info.x = x;
        mouse_info.y = y;
    }
}


void printmat(const cv::Mat &__mat, std::string __str)
{
    std::cout << "--------" << __str << "----------\n";
    for (int i=0 ; i<__mat.rows ; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0 ; j<__mat.cols ; ++j)
            std::cout << __mat.at<double>(i,j) << "  ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "-------------------------------------\n";
}


int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    int nStates = 5, nMeasurements = 2, nInputs = 1;
    Mat img(500, 900, CV_8UC3);
    KalmanFilter KF(nStates, nMeasurements, nInputs, CV_64F);
    Mat state(nStates, 1, CV_64F); /* (x, y, Vx, Vy, a) */
    Mat measurement(nMeasurements,1,CV_64F); measurement.setTo(Scalar(0));
    Mat prevMeasurement(nMeasurements,1,CV_64F); prevMeasurement.setTo(Scalar(0));
    int key = -1, dt=100, T=1000;
    float /*a=100, acclErrMag = 0.05,*/ measurementErrVar = 100, noiseVal=0.001, covNoiseVal=0.9e-4;

    namedWindow("Mouse-Kalman");
    setMouseCallback("Mouse-Kalman", on_mouse, 0);

    //while ( (char)(key=cv::waitKey(100)) != 'q' )
    {
        /// A
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(0,0) = 1;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(0,1) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(0,2) = (dt/T);
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(0,3) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(0,4) = 0.5*(dt/T)*(dt/T);

        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(1,0) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(1,1) = 1;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(1,2) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(1,3) = (dt/T);
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(1,4) = 0.5*(dt/T)*(dt/T);

        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(2,0) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(2,1) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(2,2) = 1;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(2,3) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(2,4) = (dt/T);

        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(3,0) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(3,1) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(3,2) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(3,3) = 1;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(3,4) = (dt/T);

        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(4,0) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(4,1) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(4,2) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(4,3) = 0;
        KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(4,4) = 1;


        /// Initial estimate of state variables
        KF.statePost = cv::Mat::zeros(nStates, 1,CV_64F);
        KF.statePost.at<double>(0) = mouse_info.x;
        KF.statePost.at<double>(1) = mouse_info.y;
        KF.statePost.at<double>(2) = 0;
        KF.statePost.at<double>(3) = 0;
        KF.statePost.at<double>(4) = 0;

        KF.statePre = KF.statePost;

        /// Ex or Q
        setIdentity(KF.processNoiseCov, Scalar::all(noiseVal));


        /// Initial covariance estimate Sigma_bar(t) or P'(k)
        setIdentity(KF.errorCovPre, Scalar::all(1000));

        /// Sigma(t) or P(k)
        setIdentity(KF.errorCovPost, Scalar::all(1000));

        /// B
        KF.controlMatrix = cv::Mat(nStates, nInputs,CV_64F);
        KF.controlMatrix.at<double>(0,0) = 0;
        KF.controlMatrix.at<double>(1,0) = 0;
        KF.controlMatrix.at<double>(2,0) = 0;
        KF.controlMatrix.at<double>(3,0) = 0;
        KF.controlMatrix.at<double>(4,0) = 1;

        /// H
        KF.measurementMatrix = cv::Mat::eye(nMeasurements, nStates, CV_64F);

        /// Ez or R
        setIdentity(KF.measurementNoiseCov, Scalar::all(measurementErrVar*measurementErrVar));

        printmat(KF.controlMatrix, "KF.controlMatrix");
        printmat(KF.transitionMatrix, "KF.transitionMatrix");
        printmat(KF.statePre,"KF.statePre");
        printmat(KF.processNoiseCov, "KF.processNoiseCov");
        printmat(KF.measurementMatrix, "KF.measurementMatrix");
        printmat(KF.measurementNoiseCov, "KF.measurementNoiseCov");
        printmat(KF.errorCovPost,"KF.errorCovPost");
        printmat(KF.errorCovPre,"KF.errorCovPre");
        printmat(KF.statePost,"KF.statePost");

        while (mouse_info.x < 0 || mouse_info.y < 0)
        {
            imshow("Mouse-Kalman", img);
            waitKey(30);
            continue;
        }

        while ( (char)key != 's' )
        {
            /// MAKE A MEASUREMENT
            measurement.at<double>(0) = mouse_info.x;
            measurement.at<double>(1) = mouse_info.y;

            /// MEASUREMENT UPDATE
            Mat estimated = KF.correct(measurement);

            /// STATE UPDATE
            Mat prediction = KF.predict();



            cv::Mat u(nInputs,1,CV_64F);
            u.at<double>(0,0) = 0.0 * sqrt(pow((prevMeasurement.at<double>(0) - measurement.at<double>(0)),2)
                                        + pow((prevMeasurement.at<double>(1) - measurement.at<double>(1)),2));

            /// STORE ALL DATA
            Point predictPt(prediction.at<double>(0),prediction.at<double>(1));
            Point estimatedPt(estimated.at<double>(0),estimated.at<double>(1));
            Point measuredPt(measurement.at<double>(0),measurement.at<double>(1));

            /// PLOT POINTS
#define drawCross( center, color, d )                                 \
            line( img, Point( center.x - d, center.y - d ),                \
            Point( center.x + d, center.y + d ), color, 2, CV_AA, 0); \
            line( img, Point( center.x + d, center.y - d ),                \
            Point( center.x - d, center.y + d ), color, 2, CV_AA, 0 )

            /// DRAW ALL ON IMAGE
            img = Scalar::all(0);
            drawCross( predictPt, Scalar(255,255,255), 9 );     //WHITE
            drawCross( estimatedPt, Scalar(0,0,255), 6 );       //RED
            drawCross( measuredPt, Scalar(0,255,0), 3 );        //GREEN


            line( img, estimatedPt, measuredPt, Scalar(100,255,255), 3, CV_AA, 0 );
            line( img, estimatedPt, predictPt, Scalar(0,255,255), 3, CV_AA, 0 );

            prevMeasurement = measurement;

            imshow( "Mouse-Kalman", img );
            key=cv::waitKey(10);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of the code: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9_xd4HSz8_g

As you can see that the tracking very very slow. I don't understand what is wrong with the model and why the estimation is so slow. I don't expect there should be any control input.

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: i think, your sigma(t) value is rather high ( 1000 ). it's inverse proportional to the "convergence speed". try a much smaller value

Comment: @berak that has not helped. However when I change my dt/T to 1 it seems to converge faster but suddenly in between the tracking just breaks and jumping all over the place. Here is a video with the result. I select sigma to be 1 and dt/T = 1

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XjBQrQ2Dqs

Comment: @berak I think I figured out what the problem was. I have updated the code to reflect it. You were right about the choice of values for the covariance matrices. They are the way to control the performance of the filter. For the benefit of others, I am going to leave an updated version of my code, where I have added noise to the measurement and it shows how changing the different covariance matrices, the noise can be filtered out.

Comment: hey, sorry for being lazy there in retrospect. i had much similar code for playing with the vars with trackbars, should have told you sooner .  nice you found out, anyway ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have modified my code and I am posting it for those who want to tweak it to play around for more. The main problem was the choice of covariances.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/tracking.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


struct mouse_info_struct { int x,y; };
struct mouse_info_struct mouse_info = {-1,-1}, last_mouse;

vector<Point> mousev,kalmanv;
int trackbarProcessNoiseCov = 10, trackbarMeasurementNoiseCov = 10, trackbarStateEstimationErrorCov = 10;

float processNoiseCov=10, measurementNoiseCov = 1000, stateEstimationErrorCov = 50;
int trackbarProcessNoiseCovMax=10000, trackbarMeasurementNoiseCovMax = 10000,
      trackbarStateEstimationErrorCovMax = 5000;

float processNoiseCovMin=0, measurementNoiseCovMin = 0,
      stateEstimationErrorCovMin = 0;
float processNoiseCovMax=100, measurementNoiseCovMax = 5000,
      stateEstimationErrorCovMax = 5000;

int nStates = 5, nMeasurements = 2, nInputs = 1;
KalmanFilter KF(nStates, nMeasurements, nInputs, CV_64F);

void on_mouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    last_mouse = mouse_info;
    mouse_info.x = x;
    mouse_info.y = y;
}

void on_trackbarProcessNoiseCov( int, void* )
{
    processNoiseCov = processNoiseCovMin +
        (trackbarProcessNoiseCov * (processNoiseCovMax-processNoiseCovMin)/trackbarProcessNoiseCovMax);
    setIdentity(KF.processNoiseCov, Scalar::all(processNoiseCov));
    std::cout << "\nProcess Noise Cov:     " << processNoiseCov;
    std::cout << "\nMeasurement Noise Cov: " << measurementNoiseCov << std::endl;
}

void on_trackbarMeasurementNoiseCov( int, void* )
{
    measurementNoiseCov = measurementNoiseCovMin +
(trackbarMeasurementNoiseCov * (measurementNoiseCovMax-measurementNoiseCovMin)/trackbarMeasurementNoiseCovMax);
    setIdentity(KF.measurementNoiseCov, Scalar::all(measurementNoiseCov));
    std::cout << "\nProcess Noise Cov:     " << processNoiseCov;
    std::cout << "\nMeasurement Noise Cov: " << measurementNoiseCov << std::endl;
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{
    Mat img(500, 1000, CV_8UC3);
    Mat state(nStates, 1, CV_64F);/* (x, y, Vx, Vy, a) */
    Mat measurementNoise(nMeasurements, 1, CV_64F), processNoise(nStates, 1, CV_64F);
    Mat measurement(nMeasurements,1,CV_64F); measurement.setTo(Scalar(0.0));
    Mat noisyMeasurement(nMeasurements,1,CV_64F); noisyMeasurement.setTo(Scalar(0.0));
    Mat prevMeasurement(nMeasurements,1,CV_64F); prevMeasurement.setTo(Scalar(0.0));
    Mat prevMeasurement2(nMeasurements,1,CV_64F); prevMeasurement2.setTo(Scalar(0.0));
    int key = -1, dt=50, T=1000;


    namedWindow("Mouse-Kalman");
    setMouseCallback("Mouse-Kalman", on_mouse, 0);
    createTrackbar( "Process Noise Cov", "Mouse-Kalman", &trackbarProcessNoiseCov,
            trackbarProcessNoiseCovMax, on_trackbarProcessNoiseCov );
    createTrackbar( "Measurement Noise Cov", "Mouse-Kalman", &trackbarMeasurementNoiseCov,
            trackbarMeasurementNoiseCovMax, on_trackbarMeasurementNoiseCov );

    on_trackbarProcessNoiseCov( trackbarProcessNoiseCov, 0 );
    on_trackbarMeasurementNoiseCov( trackbarMeasurementNoiseCov, 0 );

    //while ( (char)(key=cv::waitKey(100)) != 'q' )
    {
    /// A (TRANSITION MATRIX INCLUDING VELOCITY AND ACCELERATION MODEL)
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(0,0) = 1;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(0,1) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(0,2) = (dt/T);
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(0,3) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(0,4) = 0.5*(dt/T)*(dt/T);

    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(1,0) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(1,1) = 1;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(1,2) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(1,3) = (dt/T);
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(1,4) = 0.5*(dt/T)*(dt/T);

    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(2,0) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(2,1) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(2,2) = 1;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(2,3) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(2,4) = (dt/T);

    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(3,0) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(3,1) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(3,2) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(3,3) = 1;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(3,4) = (dt/T);

    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(4,0) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(4,1) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(4,2) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(4,3) = 0;
    KF.transitionMatrix.at<double>(4,4) = 1;


    /// Initial estimate of state variables
    KF.statePost = cv::Mat::zeros(nStates, 1,CV_64F);
    KF.statePost.at<double>(0) = mouse_info.x;
    KF.statePost.at<double>(1) = mouse_info.y;
    KF.statePost.at<double>(2) = 0.1;
    KF.statePost.at<double>(3) = 0.1;
    KF.statePost.at<double>(4) = 0.1;

    KF.statePre = KF.statePost;
    state = KF.statePost;

    /// Ex or Q (PROCESS NOISE COVARIANCE)
    setIdentity(KF.processNoiseCov, Scalar::all(processNoiseCov));


    /// Initial covariance estimate Sigma_bar(t) or P'(k)
    setIdentity(KF.errorCovPre, Scalar::all(stateEstimationErrorCov));

    /// Sigma(t) or P(k) (STATE ESTIMATION ERROR COVARIANCE)
    setIdentity(KF.errorCovPost, Scalar::all(stateEstimationErrorCov));

    /// B (CONTROL MATRIX)
    KF.controlMatrix = cv::Mat(nStates, nInputs,CV_64F);
    KF.controlMatrix.at<double>(0,0) = /*0.5*(dt/T)*(dt/T);//*/0;
    KF.controlMatrix.at<double>(1,0) = /*0.5*(dt/T)*(dt/T);//*/0;
    KF.controlMatrix.at<double>(2,0) = 0;
    KF.controlMatrix.at<double>(3,0) = 0;
    KF.controlMatrix.at<double>(4,0) = 1;

    /// H (MEASUREMENT MATRIX)
    KF.measurementMatrix = cv::Mat::eye(nMeasurements, nStates, CV_64F);

    /// Ez or R (MEASUREMENT NOISE COVARIANCE)
    setIdentity(KF.measurementNoiseCov, Scalar::all(measurementNoiseCov));


    while (mouse_info.x < 0 || mouse_info.y < 0)
    {
        imshow("Mouse-Kalman", img);
        waitKey(30);
        continue;
    }

    prevMeasurement.at<double>(0,0) = 0;
    prevMeasurement.at<double>(1,0) = 0;
    prevMeasurement2 = prevMeasurement;

    while ( (char)key != 's' )
    {
        /// STATE UPDATE
        Mat prediction = KF.predict();

        /// MAKE A MEASUREMENT
        measurement.at<double>(0) = mouse_info.x;
        measurement.at<double>(1) = mouse_info.y;

        /// MEASUREMENT NOISE SIMULATION
        randn( measurementNoise, Scalar(0),
          Scalar::all(sqrtf(measurementNoiseCov)));
        noisyMeasurement = measurement + measurementNoise;

        /// MEASUREMENT UPDATE
        Mat estimated = KF.correct(noisyMeasurement);

        cv::Mat u(nInputs,1,CV_64F);
        u.at<double>(0,0) = 0.0 * sqrtf(pow((prevMeasurement.at<double>(0) - measurement.at<double>(0)),2)
                    + pow((prevMeasurement.at<double>(1) - measurement.at<double>(1)),2));

        /// STORE ALL DATA
        Point noisyPt(noisyMeasurement.at<double>(0),noisyMeasurement.at<double>(1));
        Point estimatedPt(estimated.at<double>(0),estimated.at<double>(1));
        Point measuredPt(measurement.at<double>(0),measurement.at<double>(1));


        /// PLOT POINTS
#define drawCross( center, color, d )                                 \
        line( img, Point( center.x - d, center.y - d ),                \
        Point( center.x + d, center.y + d ), color, 2, CV_AA, 0); \
        line( img, Point( center.x + d, center.y - d ),                \
        Point( center.x - d, center.y + d ), color, 2, CV_AA, 0 )

        /// DRAW ALL ON IMAGE
        img = Scalar::all(0);
        drawCross( noisyPt, Scalar(255,255,255), 9 );     //WHITE
        drawCross( estimatedPt, Scalar(0,0,255), 6 );       //RED
        drawCross( measuredPt, Scalar(0,255,0), 3 );        //GREEN


        line( img, estimatedPt, measuredPt, Scalar(100,255,255), 3, CV_AA, 0 );
        line( img, estimatedPt, noisyPt, Scalar(0,255,255), 3, CV_AA, 0 );

        imshow( "Mouse-Kalman", img );
        key=cv::waitKey(dt);
        prevMeasurement = measurement;
    }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's good to hear that you found the cause of your problem.  You could make your answer more helpful for future readers by explaining *how* you diagnosed it, and in particular, which evidence will identify this problem when it's seen elsewhere.